# Laravel Sail Failed to Build

Tags: docker, laravel-8, laravel-sail

I'm struggling to get Laravel Sail working. Following the instructions from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#getting-started-on-windows) I'm not really understanding why the container is failing to build. I don't have any docker experience.

**./vendor/bin/sail php -v**
returns "Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded"

**./vendor/bin/sail build --no-cache** fails who what reason?

Sorry if not much to go on, anyone who could point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

```
wazimshizm@Surface-Pro-6:~/code/sports$ ./vendor/bin/sail php -v 
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
PHP 8.0.7 (cli) (built: Jun  4 2021 21:26:10) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.7, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.7, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
wazimshizm@Surface-Pro-6:~/code/sports$ ./vendor/bin/sail build --no-cache
mysql uses an image, skipping
redis uses an image, skipping
meilisearch uses an image, skipping
mailhog uses an image, skipping
selenium uses an image, skipping
Building laravel.test
[+] Building 64.7s (8/16)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                     0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.42kB                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                        0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                        0.1s
 => => transferring context: 906B                                                                        0.0s
 => [ 1/12] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/12] WORKDIR /var/www/html                                                                 0.0s
 => [ 3/12] RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime && echo UTC > /etc/timezone               0.5s
 => ERROR [ 4/12] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unz  64.0s
------
 > [ 4/12] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg     && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg     && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C     && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev        php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd        php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached        php8.0-imap php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring        php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap        php8.0-intl php8.0-readline        php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap        php8.0-redis     && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -     && apt-get install -y nodejs     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -     && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*:
#7 1.140 Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
#7 1.546 Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
#7 3.365 Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
#7 4.008 Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
#7 4.747 Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 Packages [33.4 kB]
#7 4.889 Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages [177 kB]
#7 5.676 Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [1275 kB]
#7 11.34 Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [11.3 MB]
#7 63.42 Reading package lists...
#7 63.94 E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 5h 15min 5s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
#7 63.94 E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 5h 15min 24s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
#7 63.94 E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 5h 15min 54s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg     && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg     && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C     && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev        php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd        php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached        php8.0-imap php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring        php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap        php8.0-intl php8.0-readline        php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap        php8.0-redis     && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -     && apt-get install -y nodejs     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -     && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*]: exit code: 100
ERROR: Service 'laravel.test' failed to build : Build failed
wazimshizm@Surface-Pro-6:~/code/sports$ ./vendor/bin/sail build --no-cache
mysql uses an image, skipping
redis uses an image, skipping
meilisearch uses an image, skipping
mailhog uses an image, skipping
selenium uses an image, skipping
Building laravel.test
[+] Building 64.5s (8/16)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 38B                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                                          0.0s
 => [ 1/12] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 99B                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/12] WORKDIR /var/www/html                                                                 0.0s
 => [ 3/12] RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime && echo UTC > /etc/timezone               0.5s
 => ERROR [ 4/12] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unz  63.8s
------
 > [ 4/12] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg     && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg     && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C     && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev        php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd        php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached        php8.0-imap php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring        php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap        php8.0-intl php8.0-readline        php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap        php8.0-redis     && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -     && apt-get install -y nodejs     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -     && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*:
#7 1.142 Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
#7 1.219 Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
#7 3.044 Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
#7 3.684 Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
#7 4.414 Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [11.3 MB]
#7 56.13 Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [1275 kB]
#7 61.75 Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 Packages [33.4 kB]
#7 62.16 Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages [177 kB]
#7 63.17 Reading package lists...
#7 63.76 E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 5h 12min 49s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
#7 63.76 E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 5h 13min 7s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
#7 63.76 E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 5h 13min 38s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg     && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg     && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C     && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev        php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd        php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached        php8.0-imap php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring        php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap        php8.0-intl php8.0-readline        php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap        php8.0-redis     && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -     && apt-get install -y nodejs     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -     && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*]: exit code: 100
ERROR: Service 'laravel.test' failed to build : Build failed
```

Comment: restarted computer and it worked. not sure why.

Comment: Look like it is just the connection issue...

Comment: Hi . have you solved this issue ?  I got struck at the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
    build:
        context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        args:
            WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
    image: sail-8.0/app
```

Change 8.1 to ...runtimes/8.0 and and sail-8.0 , then try sail up

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue when Docker was installed with Snap. Removed and installed with Apt and the issue was no more.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34626421)